# Comparison metric for two open contours

Tags: image-processing

I'm validating an image segmentation algorithm applied to 2D images. The algorithm generates a contour segment, i.e. a set of connected pixels that form a freecurve in 2D space. The idea is to compare this set of pixels with a ground-truth, in my case another contour segment manually traced by an expert. An image showing what would be a segmentation result and the corresponding manual (ground-truth) segmentation is shown below:

[image]

I'm trying to think of an adequate comparison metric to validate the segmentation results. Ideally the best metric would be the point-to-point euclidean distance between corresponding pairs of pixels on each segment, however (as seen in previous figure) the segments don't have the same length (i.e. differ by the total number of pixels) so pixel-to-pixel comparisons have to be discarded.

Can you suggest me an adequate metric for validating my algorithm? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each pixel in the ground truth, take the distance to the nearest pixel in the segmentation result. Then take the sum of that for all ground truth pixels as the total error.

That's basically recall weighted by distance. If you start with the pixels in the result, it would resemble precision instead.

Comment: Thanks Junuxx. I implemented a similar approach: for each pixel in the segmentation result I computed the minimum distance to the ground truth curve. Then I took the maximum of this set of minimum distances as the comparison metric. This is known as [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)

Answer (score 1):

If the curves are closed, you can compute the area between the curves. If you can tell which pixels belong to a segment, that is as easy as computing `XOR` set of the 2 pixel sets.

Here is an example using that I've created using Matlab:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could divide each line into n segments of equal length, then compute the euclidean distance between each segment and its pair on the other line.

Comment: Since both lines (free-curves) don't have the same length, when dividing then into n segments I'll end up with segments also if different length. How to compute the euclidean distance between two of such segments when their size is not the same?

Comment: Actually I implemented an approach similar to the one suggested by Junnux, see above.

Comment: Glad you found a method that works.  To answer your question, the size of the segment does not affect the calculation of the distance between.  You could choose the midpoint, front, or back of each segment and calculate the distance between them.  One thing I would caution about Junnux answer is that I don't think it will give any error for matching line segments of different lengths.  Each pixel will be a distance of 0 from its nearest neighbor but the curves will not be the same.